# SDL Web 8 Audience Manager issue

Tags: web8, audience-manager

We had recently, SDL Web 8 set up in our development environment. But we have done required settings for Audience Manager set up for one of the Publications.

We have one Contact Form in Website, when we are submitting the form we are getting the error:

> Unable to find a Publication mapping for the current Publication: 121. Try adding a synchronization target to this Publication.

Could u please let us know ASAP?

Answer (score 8):

It would be great if the question has been asked with more details and provide some clear information - ensure following:

- Ensure a Synchronization Target has been created in CME and marked as Active
- Profile and Tracking has been setup and their URL is mentioned in the Sync Target with appropriate authentication mode. Refer the documentation mentioned by Philippe. Below Image depicts this:
  [image]
- Now open the Properties of your concerned publication (from the execption it seems the publication with TCM ID 121)
- Navigate to the "Audience Management" tab
- Ensure an appropriate Sync Target is selected, Appropriate Address Book/s are appearing in the "Allowed Address Book" section and "Synchronize Address Book" checkbox is selected (else for every contact add/update/delete, you need to synchronize it manually)
  [image]

I hope this should help you move forward with the issue.

Answer (score 4):

As the exception suggest, please try to configure audience manager synchronization target in your publication 121 properties. 
Follow the instructions in the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C914B4B3-946F-44B9-928C-F41D516D6326).

Can you explain what you configured so far for Audience Manager?
Did you create a synchronization target? Did you install the Audience Manager microservices? Did you create an address book for your contacts? Did you configure the synchronization target on your publication? Which code do you use to create the contacts in your form submit?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't have a Publication Mapping in Topology Manager that maps the current Publication (121) to the current environment / Web application.

To fix that, you need to a mapping as described on the following page of the documentation: [Mapping a Publication to a Web application](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-92B9DFBA-E3F6-43F1-8B36-D8B064218399).

After that, you'll need to change something on the Audience Manager tab of the Publication and save, so that it saves the Synchronization Target settings to the newly created mapping.